# Apollo-client using cached data with wrong parameters

Tags: reactjs, apollo-client

I'm using the `@apollo/client` module to handle queries.

These queries are based on URL parameters, as so:

```
/users/:groupId/book/:viewId
```

both groupId and viewId are used as variables for my query:

```
  const { groupId, viewId } = useParams<{ groupId: string; viewId: string }>();

  const result = useViewSettingsQuery({
    variables: { groupId, id: viewId },
    skip: !viewId,
    fetchPolicy: 'cache-and-network',
    nextFetchPolicy: 'cache-first',
  });
```

Now, the problem is, when switching from one view to another, Apollo Client will always display previous data for half a second, before displaying the actual data.

I took a look at the repository issues and thought it might be related to [this one](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/9379), but unfortunately, my server returns a proper unique ID for each query.

How comes that the previous data is always used first, even though the variables differ from one query to the next?